# Get Dropdown Selected value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My view contains dropdownlist. populating dropdownlist code :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var architects = (from ar in db.ArchitectMasters where ar.IsActive == 1 select ar).ToList();
  ProjectMaster ps = new ProjectMaster();
  ViewBag.ArchitectID = new SelectList(architects, "ArchitectID", "ArchitectName",ps.ArchitectID);
  return View();
}
```

View Code :

```
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Architect")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.Hidden("ArchitectID")
         @Html.DropDownList("ArchitectID ", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ArchitectID)
    </div>
```

Post Create Method :

```
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectMaster projectmaster, long ArchitectID, FormCollection data)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //string dropDownSelectedValue = data.Get("ArchitectName");
            //ViewBag.ArchitectID = data["ArchitectName"];
            long architectname = long.Parse(ArchitectID.ToString());
             db.ProjectMasters.Add(projectmaster);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

how do i get selected value of dropdownlist in my controller ? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can retrieve the selected value in the ActionResult from the Model/FormCollection. Below ways usually followed to get the selected value of dropdownlist in controller.

```
public ActionResult Create(ProjectMaster projectmaster, long ArchitectID, FormCollection data)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int id=projectmaster.ArchitectID;
           //another way int id=data["ArchitectID"];  

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```